# Send Whatsapp from Message bird in ASP.net

Tags: messagebird

We have an application in VB.Net which currently send a pdf via automatic email on certain event done in application. Now we want to send the PDF in whatsapp via messagebird api. Below is a sample from messagebird

```
    Dim WhatsAppClient As Client = Client.CreateDefault(YourAccessKey)
    Dim language As HsmLanguage = New HsmLanguage()
    language.Code = "en"
    language.Policy = HsmLanguagePolicy.Deterministic
    Dim params As List(Of HsmLocalizableParameter) = New List(Of HsmLocalizableParameter)()
    Dim hsmParamName As HsmLocalizableParameter = New HsmLocalizableParameter()
    hsmParamName.Default = "Bob"
    Dim hsmParamWhen As HsmLocalizableParameter = New HsmLocalizableParameter()
    hsmParamName.Default = "Tomorrow"
    params.Add(hsmParamName)
    params.Add(hsmParamWhen)
    Dim hsmContent As HsmContent = New HsmContent()
    hsmContent.Namespace = HsmNamespace
    hsmContent.TemplateName = "verification"
    hsmContent.Language = language
    hsmContent.Params = params
    Dim content As Content = New Content()
    content.Hsm = hsmContent
    Dim request As ConversationStartRequest = New ConversationStartRequest()
    request.To = [To]
    request.Type = ContentType.hsm
    request.Content = content
    request.ChannelId = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    Dim message As MessageBird.Objects.Message = WhatsAppClient.StartConversation(request)
```

I am getting  errors in "request.Type = ContentType.hsm"   "HSM is not a member of string"

and in last line -
Value of type 'MessageBird.Objects.Conversations.Conversation' cannot be converted to 'MessageBird.Objects.Message'
Any push in the correct direction will help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the MessageBird SDK I can see that https://github.com/messagebird/csharp-rest-api/blob/752b809245a72674dadf469b6f9641dcf697a4e7/MessageBird/Objects/Conversations/Content.cs the call should be

```
request.Type = ContentType.Hsm
```

Here is an example of it https://github.com/messagebird/csharp-rest-api/blob/0c5bbd13736e9f0fb1719246232698d8039915ad/Examples/Message/SendTemplatedMessage.cs
On your last error, the startConversation signature is as follows as per https://github.com/messagebird/csharp-rest-api/blob/0c5bbd13736e9f0fb1719246232698d8039915ad/MessageBird/ConversationsClient.cs:

```
public Conversation StartConversation(ConversationStartRequest startRequest)
```

This may explain the error you are seeing.

Couple of questions:

- Are the above compilation errors?.
- Where did you get the example you have illustrated above?.

Comment: the above errors are compilation error which are resolved, code executed correctly but the message is not received. I have raised the issue to message bird support yesterday along with conversation id which they asked, may be today they answer.